# Can't figure out why object can't read it's own value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm writing a piece of code for my brother about pokemon and the Pokeball object isn't telling me its value and I can't tell why. Here is the code:

```
    let pokeball = document.getElementById("pokeballType");
    let catchRate = document.getElementById('catchRate')
    console.log(`the type of pokeball is ${typeof(pokeball)}.`);
    if (pokeball.options[pokeball.selectedIndex].value === 'timerBall') {
        timerBall.style.display = 'inline';
        timerBallLabel.style.display = 'inline';
        console.log('Working')
    }

    <select name = 'pokeball2' id="pokeballType">
        <option value=1 selected = 'selected'>Pokeball</option>
        <option value=2>Ultra Ball</option>
        <option value=1.5>Great Ball</option>
        <option value=3.5>Dusk Ball if used inside cave</option>
        <option value=4>Quick ball if used on first turn</option>
        <option value='timerBall'>Timer Ball</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: What are you getting? Have you looked at your console for errors? Do you have the `script` executing AFTER the HTML has been parsed. Please provide more information.

Comment: Need more information to help you solve the problem

Comment: You need a [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event that fires when you change a value in de selectbox. Otherwise it will only run at startup.

Answer (score 1):

You need a  [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event that fires when you change a value in de selectbox. Otherwise it will only run at startup.

```js
let pokeball = document.getElementById("pokeballType");

pokeball.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (pokeball.value === 'timerBall') {
    console.log("timerBall selected...");
  }else{
    console.log(pokeball.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<select name = 'pokeball2' id="pokeballType">
    <option value=1 selected = 'selected'>Pokeball</option>
    <option value=2>Ultra Ball</option>
    <option value=1.5>Great Ball</option>
    <option value=3.5>Dusk Ball if used inside cave</option>
    <option value=4>Quick ball if used on first turn</option>
    <option value='timerBall'>Timer Ball</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fixes and they looked very promising, however when I implemented them they still came up with the same error which is                                                            **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**      This is the same error I had when I tried to do this before, if you can fix this I'd be very grateful and I'll attach any bit of code you want.

Comment: @DiscoLlamaMan that just means the `getElementById` cant find an element. Are you sure your selectbox has the id `pokeballType`? Another option could be that you're loading the script file inside the `head` tag. Try moving it to right before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so so much, you were right, it was because I put the script tag in the head, instead of the body. I think that is why a lot of my stuff hasn't worked in the past

Comment: @DiscoLlamaMan Cool! Quick explanation: JS will execute ones it is downloaded, it does not wait for the page to load. This is why your script was not working. You were trying to access the selecbox which has not been loaded yet. By putting the script at the bottom of the page we make sure that all the HTML elements are loaded before the script executes.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your `script` is executing after all the HTML has been parsed and after a selection has been made in your `select`. Your code does not show any event handling so we might assume that you are trying to get the selected value before any selection has been made.

Here's what you should be setting up and take note that it's much simpler to get the selected option value by simply asking for the `value` of the `select` than getting the `selectedIndex` value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <select name = 'pokeball2' id="pokeballType">
        <option value=1 selected = 'selected'>Pokeball</option>
        <option value=2>Ultra Ball</option>
        <option value=1.5>Great Ball</option>
        <option value=3.5>Dusk Ball if used inside cave</option>
        <option value=4>Quick ball if used on first turn</option>
        <option value='timerBall'>Timer Ball</option>
  </select>
    
  <script>
    let pokeball = document.getElementById("pokeballType");
    
    // Set up an even handler for when the value of the select changes
    pokeball.addEventListener("change", function(){
      if (pokeball.value === 'timerBall') {
        console.log('Working')
      }    
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```